# How can I change dpi manifest settings in a premake VS C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, premake

Currently, I call SetProcessDPIAware() but [the docs recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process#setting-default-awareness-with-the-application-manifest) using a manifest:

> We recommended that you specify the default process DPI awareness via
> a manifest setting. While specifying the default via API is supported,
> it is not recommended.

Additionally, I find that on some machines calling `SetProcessDPIAware()` causes the window title to disappear and reappear which causes the window to move down. I'm trying to have a persistent window position and this flicker is making my window slide down the screen after repeated runs.

How do I set dpi settings in the manifest in Visual Studio? How would I make premake generate a vcxproj with that setting?

*[How to run correctly with a high DPI setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e) describes some of the answer I'm looking for, but the menus are different for C#.*

Comment: "*on some machines calling `SetProcessDPIAware()` causes the window title to disappear and reappear which causes the window to move down*" - you are supposed to call `SetProcessDPIAware()` **before** creating any GUI windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change in Visual Studio:

1. Open properties for the Startup Project
2. Manifest Tool > Input and Output
3. Change DPI Awareness to Per Monitor High DPI Aware

To change in premake, set [dpiawareness](https://premake.github.io/docs/dpiawareness/) inside your [project](https://premake.github.io/docs/project/) block:

```lua
project( "ProjectName" )
    kind "WindowedApp"

    dpiawareness "HighPerMonitor"
```